# Calling a function before it is declared, browser independent?

Tags: javascript

If I do this in my `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
```

And inside foo.js I do this:

```
var foo = new Foo();
function Foo()
{
   //code here
}
```

Would this code reliably instantiate the variable `foo` even though its included above the function definition, or should I move it instead to the bottom of the file, like this:

```
function Foo()
{
   //code here
}
var foo = new Foo();
```

Comment: You might find this article helpful: [http://kangax.github.com/nfe/](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example will work in any browser that follow the ECMAScript standard (all do at least with regards to this question).

See sections 10.3-10.5 of the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

First the local scope is set up and just thereafter the function body is actually run.

Read 10.5 (the section is really not very long) to understand why @meder's answer is right.

#### If you don't want to read the specs yourself:

10.5 tells to declare variables in that order (overwriting if a some name occurs twice):

Inheriting from outer scope = setting will affect the outer scope:

- Variables of the surrounding scope.
- The own function name.

Local scope = setting won't affect the outer scope:

- The parameters (left to right).
- The arguments object.
- Declare all the inner variables (not overwriting the current value if any, `undefined` if none, yet)

*All in all:*

Returns the function x itself:

```
function x() {
    return x;
}
```

Returns the parameter x:

```
function x(x) {
    return x;
}
```

Returns the inner function x:

```
function x(x) {
    return x; // the return does no harm, x is already set
    function x() {} // before the actual body is evaluated
}
```

Also returns the inner function x:

```
function x(x) {
    var x; // in this case a no-op 
    return x;
    function x() {}
}
```

Returns 42:

```
function x(x) {
    var x = 42; // overwrite x in local scope
    return x;
    function x() {}
}
```

Returns the second argument:

```
function x(x,x) { // assign left to right, last one "wins"
    return x; // arguments[0] would still name the first argument
}
```

Returns 2 when `x` is called the second time, as x is set to the inner function:

```
function x() {
    x = function() { return 2; } // set x in outer scope
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: +1 for not using "hoisting", but note that the relevant section is entering the [global context](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.1), not function context, which primarily affects the value of `this`.

Comment: I don't understand how that specification answers my question? Can you translate it in english?

Comment: In simple terms, for global code, `this` is set to the global object, then function declarations are processed, then variable declarations, then executable statements. When entering each function, a similar process occurs but setting the value for `this` and scope are more complex.

Comment: @RobG yeah, I neglected `this` on purpose. :)

Answer (score 4):

It's only necessary to move it above if you define it via `var`, such as:

```
var Foo = function(){};
var foo = new Foo;
```

Otherwise, to my knowledge the interpreter reads function definitions in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know, JS does this to your code due to hoisting:

```
var foo;          //var declarations hoisted up
function Foo(){   //function declarations hoisted up
   //code here
}
foo = new Foo();  //the operation
```

so it should be fine. However, I'd not rely solely on hoisting because, for me at least, it's hard to debug when declarations are all over the place. For readability, order the code this way:

- variable declarations
- functions
- operations

---

[code 1:](http://jsfiddle.net/3mYFp/4/)

```
console.log(foo); //undefined
var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo); //Foo
function Foo(){
   //code here
}
console.log(foo); //Foo

//acts like:
var foo;          //var declaration hoisted up
function Foo(){}  //function declaration hoisted up
console.log(foo); //undefined
foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo); //Foo
console.log(foo); //Foo
```

[code 2:](http://jsfiddle.net/3mYFp/5/)

```
console.log(foo); //undefined
function Foo(){
   //code here
}
console.log(foo); //undefined
var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo); //Foo

//acts like:
var foo;          //var declaration hoisted up
function Foo(){}  //function declaration hoisted up
console.log(foo); //undefined
console.log(foo); //undefined
foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo); //Foo
```

Comment: I think he's asking about the `Foo` function declaration in the first example instead of the `foo` variable declaration, as in that example the function is being invoked before its declaration appears.

Comment: @amnotiam Yes,the variable can be named anything, I'm wondering if it'll be reliably instantiated if put above the definition of the Foo() function

Comment: It also hoists the function statement and turns it into `var Foo = function Foo () { // ... };`

Comment: @ClickUpvote: By *instantiated*, you're asking if the `new Foo()` will work because it happens "out of order" with respect to the declaration of `function Foo() {...}`, right? ...anyway, the answer is yes. Function declarations happen before any code in the enclosing scope is executed.

Comment: @Peter [function statements (functions in variables) are not hoisted up](http://jsfiddle.net/3mYFp/6/). Only it's `var Foo` gets hoisted, not the `Foo = function Foo(){}`

Comment: I think @Peter was using the variable assignment syntax to illustrate that the function will be available as though that code was at the top of the function. It's just a little confusing that he used that syntax to illustrate it.