# using var keyword in while loop definition

Tags: javascript, while-loop, var

In JavaScript for loop I can use `var` keyword in loop definition something like that:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) ...
```

I know scope of the variable `i` is not inside the loop but inside function where loop is declared. This it a better notation than declaring local variable `i` outside of the loop (the worst notation is declare `i` variable in the beggining of function body):

```
var i;
for (i=0; i<10; i++) ...
```

My question is about while loop. I'm not able declare variable in while loop definition something like this:

```
while((var match = re.exec(pattern)) != null) ...
```

I have to use `var` keyword outside of the while loop.

```
var match;
while((match = re.exec(pattern)) != null) ...
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: http://es5.github.io/x12.html#x12.6.3

Comment: That is correct, you declare the variable before the while loop, not inside it.

Comment: what are you talking about "the worst notation is declare i variable in the beggining of function body". I'm pretty sure javascript hoists all variables to the beginning of the function body

Comment: Forget the "JavaScript hoists variables" part, it is a beginners mistake. I think a gave a proper/brief overview in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10792121/.

Comment: Im confused on what you are saying. You are saying that javascript does NOT hoist variables to the top of the scope? Just would like to confirm

Comment: @ScottMitchell I mean it is the worst notation when I'm doing it manually, if interpretter is doing so I don't care. For a loops it is not nice  to have `var i;` lot of lines of code and finally few lines with `i` variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong?

No you are not. That's just how the syntax is defined. The `while` loop only accepts an expression, while the `for` loop can also be used with a `var` declaration.

See https://es5.github.io/#x12.6:

```
while ( Expression ) Statement
for ( ExpressionNoIn_opt; Expression_opt ; Expression_opt ) Statement
for ( var VariableDeclarationListNoIn; Expression_opt ; Expression_opt ) Statement
```